# android - Admob ads doesn't show with telephone card (2G or 3G) but admob shows Ads with WIFI

Tags: android, wifi, admob, 3g

I'm trying to show ads with admob on 2g or 3g. WIFI works great. With WIFI I see a lot of Ads. But when I change to telephone card, I see nothing. Somebody knows why?

EDIT:

Upps. I have it.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Show Ads
}
```

I'm checking first WIFI and then showing ads. What a logic. After WIFI delete its working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use the conditions like this

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();

and then use it like that:

if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile // so call the ads method
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi // so call the ads method. 
}
```

else use the code like below also

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//For 3G check
boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
//For WiFi Check
boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();

System.out.println(is3g + " net " + isWifi);

if (!is3g && !isWifi) 
{ 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please make sure your Network Connection is ON ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
 else 
{ 
        " Your method what you want to do "
}
```